# Rotating svg element looks like bouncing slightly

Tags: html, css, svg

I looked at the existing question related yo my query but could not get help.

I am Using basic animation of css3. Below is the fiddle..

https://jsfiddle.net/gamerVinod/d21c6bcb/5/

Below is the css

```
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
       transform: rotate(0deg);
       transform-origin: center;
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform-origin: center;
    }
}

.rotate-element {
    animation: rotate 1s infinite linear;
}
```

Whenever i use SVG and rotate it then it bounces slightly.

I am not able to find out whether it is due to SVG path or anything else.Can someone please let me know the reason of it and how to fix it?

Comment: You're not rotating on the circle's center.

Comment: i tried using "transform-origin: center;", did not help, updated the fiddle

Comment: If your circle isn't centered in the box, then `transform-origin:center;` won't help. I suspect your circle isn't circular either. You're using bezier curves rather than arcs.

Comment: i also suspect about the circle, i downloaded this SVG from internet not created by me. Please let me know if you have svg created using arcs.

Comment: We'll be happy to help if you run into problems creating your own SVG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Ouroborus said, bezier curves can only approximate circular arcs.  If you need to rotate those shapes then, unless your shape is carefully and accurately crafted, you are likely to see some shimmy.

You could use the arc (`A`) path element instead. But you don't need to. By far the simplest solution here is to use an actual `<circle>`.

```css
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}

.rotate-element {
    animation: rotate 1s infinite linear;
}

.parent{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  text-align: center;
}

.child{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <svg class="child rotate-element" version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="13.25" opacity="0.2" fill="none"
            stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"/> 
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="13.25" fill="none"
            stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"
            stroke-dasharray="6 80"/> 
  </svg>
</div>
```

Here I am using two circles with thick strokes (lines) and transparent fill.  The one at the back is semi-transparent (like the original SVG).  The one on top has only part of it's stroke drawn by using a dash array.